# Looping through elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I am trying to loop through some navigation HTML because I need to modify some items dynamically. Specifically how would I loop through each item with class Droppable and get the jQuery object for certain children. I have posted my code below with a bunch of asterisks(*) denoting notes of the things I need to manipulate as jquery objects.

```
<nav id="sitenav">
    <ul class="container ul-reset">
        <li class="droppable "> ****** foreach of these
            <a class="RootNode" id="Help" href="javascript:;">HELP</a> ****** I need this
            <div class="mega-menu">
                <div class="container cf">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                        <ul class="ul-reset"> ****** and I need this 
                            <a class="heading disabled" id="Help_Help" href="javascript:;">
                                <h3>Help</h3>
                            </a>
                            <a id="ContactUs" href="/ContactUs/">Contact Us</a>
                            <a id="UserGuides" href="/Help/">User Guides</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

        {more lis with the same structure...}

    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried the below but I get an error that this doesn't have a find method, which I thought it would because I thought this would be the current jQuery wrapped DOM element from the each loop.

```
$("li.droppable").each(function (index) {
    var header = this.find("a.RootNode");
    var col = this.find("ul.ul-reset");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `.find()` is a jQuery method and you can't call it on DOM object  `this`.

You could instead call the `.find()` method on jQuery object `$(this)`, so it should be :

```
$("li.droppable").each(function(index) {
  var $this  = $(this);

  var header = $this.find("a.RootNode");
  var col    = $this.find("ul.ul-reset");
});
```

Comment: Best to stay DRY and cache `var $this = $(this);`